# jquery slideUp is not working

Tags: jquery, html

Am new to web designing. Am trying to create a website with sliding menu, but unfortunately am stuck up with jquery in initial stage itself.

Here is my HTML Page (index.html)

```
<div class="titlebar" align="middle">
    <div class="nav">
        <div id="menu_products" class="menu">
            <a href="#" class="prodlink">Products</a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_logo" class="menu">
            <b><a href="">company name</a></b>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_account" class="menu">
            <a href=""> Account</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products" id="productlist">
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <a href="" class="prod_nav">Computers</a>
            <a href="" class="prod_nav">Laptops</a>
            <a href="" class="prod_nav">Tablets</a>
            <a href="" class="prod_nav">Smart Phones</a>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Here is my jquery (index.js)

```
$("a.prodlink").click(function() {
    $(".products").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Have you added link to jquery.js file.?

Comment: @OptimusPrime yes I have added the link.

Comment: @PavelPatino : Am using both latest Firefox and Chromium browsers. For web designing - Aptana Studio 3. First I used javascript. But it didn't worked. Then I tried jquery, it also didn't worked. Am I missing anything? 
Like design concepts, div  alignment, etc.

Comment: @MohamedMatheen css has nothing to do with your jquery's sliding up or anything. If you still need help, make a jsFiddle from your code or post more of your html,js code.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It is solved.
Problem is I haven't linked it properly. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the JS is just failing to wait for DOM ready. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.prodlink").click(function() {
        $(".products").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Am sorry,but it is not working. Should I have to check my css?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `slideToggle` for your particular problem.

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/tchow002/LvVAu/6/ for a working example.

If nothing is happening when you click your products link please look at the answer by @Pavel Patino.